# Adjusting position of elements in second column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I vertically center the items in the second column like this:

[image]

I am using **Bootstrap 3**, and there doesn't seem to be a clear cut way of achieving this.

Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/sqygt2gt/3/.

```
<div class="row remove-row-margins">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="fluid-media">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QyIIeQbL1Zo" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 2em">
            <h3 style="margin-top: 0px;">Get in touch to create your account today</h3>
        </div>
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Brand Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Contact Number">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign up</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **flex** in **`.remove-row-margins`**. Use **`align-items: center`** to vertically align the items center.

> **[More help to understand flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)**

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c4L73o2u/)**

```
.remove-row-margins {
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```